# Is there a way to see if someone tried to access to a private Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless-networking

Is there a way to see if someone tried to access to a private Wi-Fi?

And also... is there a way to see devices which has connected, a sort of 'chronology' of Wi-Fi accesses?

My modem is Alice Gate VoIP 2 Plus Wi-Fi.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the make and model of your access point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your wifi signal provider device. I have a FritzBox! that can be configurated to send me an email when a new device is registered, or even if some device tries to access.